# Error running chromedriver when executing script using cron

Tags: python, bash, cron

I have a script called stock_automation.sh that rus a python script called stock_automation.py.
When I run it from terminal it works perfectly fine, but when I try to use cron to run it automatically, it gives an error with the selenium chromedriver.

my crontab entry is the following: `25 14 * * *  /home/user/project-scrapers/stock_automation.sh >> /home/daniel/amazon-project-scrapers/stock_automation.sh.log 2>&1`

The content of my script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello!"
source /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/bin/activate
python /home/user/project-scrapers/stock_automation.py
```

The error in my logfile is the following:

```
    Hello!
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:117: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project-scrapers/stock_automation.py", line 235, in <module>
    dfs = stock(webpage, MAXIMUM_VALUE)
  File "/home/user/project-scrapers/stock_automation.py", line 24, in stock
    executable_path=executable_path)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-scrapers-kMVxSu_o/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
If you suspect this is an IPython 7.13.0 bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org
You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.
Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Comment: Error message seems pretty clear about the cause: `Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.` and `(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`. Do you (have to) run something else in your shell before this command to make it work? Because it seems you need Chrome to be running for it to work.

Comment: This should run selenium webdriver. But when I run the script using the terminal it works perfectly fine. I don't know if I have to add additional configuration for selenium

Comment: Maybe is lacking some environment variables when running through `cron`. You could try to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of your `crontab` and then try to run the job again.

Comment: @hads0m : The OP already runs the script as _bash_, as you can see from the #! line.

Comment: @TheDan : The most likely reason is something in the environment. Compare the environment which you have in your shell, to that when you run it from cron, and see whether you find differences regarding to the selenium or Python configuration.

Comment: @TheDan : I would also verify whether you run the same Python in both cases, not only the version (cron seems to run Python 3.7), but also the installation location. After all, the message says that your Python installation is incomplete. Maybe you have some broken Python laying around, which happens to be used from your cron job.